# Generating a clickable SVG floorplan, where I need to manually "close off" rooms to make them clickable

Tags: svg, path

This is a follow-up to my previous question [Converting a floorplan image to SVG paths (in Inkscape, or alternative)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150279/converting-a-floorplan-image-to-svg-paths-in-inkscape-or-alternative).

I start with a JPEG of a floorplan:

[image]

I want "close off" the rooms, and make each of them individually clickable (and also to make the background transparent):

[image]

I follow the guide [How To Create SVG Paths Easily Using The GIMP](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/04/26/how-to-create-svg-paths-easily-using-the-gimp/).

However, my problem is that I don't want the user to see those (red) lines that I added to close off the rooms, while still having each room as clickable SVG path, so that my app can react to user clicks in each room.

E.g I will change

```
<path fill="orange" stroke="orange" stroke-width="1"
      d="M 506.00,167.00
       C 506.00,167.00 470.00,168.00 470.00,168.00
[ ... snip]
         507.00,182.00 506.00,167.00 506.00,167.00 Z" />
```

to

```
<path (click)="onRoomClick(5)"    <==== click handler
      fill="orange" stroke="orange" stroke-width="1"
      d="M 506.00,167.00
       C 506.00,167.00 470.00,168.00 470.00,168.00
[ ... snip]
         507.00,182.00 506.00,167.00 506.00,167.00 Z" />
```

I had though to use Inkscape to open the SVG paths file created by the GIMP, then import the original JEPG, and manually edit the resultant merged SVG so that the JPEG is visible and the paths are invisible but clickable.

However,  when I do that ***the images do not align*** :-(

How can I achieve my objectives?

- Starting with a JPEG floorplan
- manually close off rooms
- and generate an SVG
- where the user sees the original image
- and does not see an image with the closed-off room paths
- but they are clickable and represent exactly the original image

Any solution, any combination of tools, but as simple as possible, as some floor-plans may become [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topkap%C4%B1_Palace#/media/File:Harem_Topkapi_Palace_plan(2).svg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use GIMP because it only has very basic vector capabilities. GIMP is a raster image editor. It's not the right kind of software.

The whole thing can be made in Inkscape. You can import your jpeg as a guide to redraw it. Delete the jpeg afterwards.

Enable the page grid and snapping to grid to make the following steps easier. I assume basic familiarity with how to use Inkscape. If you don't know how to use it there are tutorials on youtube. This isn't a tutorial, just the basic steps.

1. With the pen tool draw the outer walls with a thick stroke
2. Draw the inner walls with thinner strokes
3. Add filled rectangles (no stroke) to cover over each room
4. Apply onclick interactivity to each rectangle in the Object Properties panel.
5. Set all the rectangle fill alpha opacities to 0%.

[See Example](https://svgshare.com/i/_ad.svg)

Here's the SVG code for the above example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg width="175mm" height="125mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 175 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g transform="translate(70.8 -14.7)">
  <g fill="none" stroke="#000">
   <path d="m-68.8 66.5v-49.8h171v121h-64" stop-color="#000000" stroke-width="4.05"/>
   <path d="m-68.8 87.8v49.8h85.3" stop-color="#000000" stroke-width="4.05"/>
   <g stroke-width="1.9">
    <path d="m-68.8 52.3h21.3"/>
    <path d="m-26.1 52.3h14.2v-35.6"/>
    <path d="m-11.9 52.3h14.2v14.2"/>
    <path d="m2.32 87.8v21.3h-28.4"/>
    <path d="m-47.5 109h-21.3"/>
    <path d="m2.32 109v28.4"/>
    <path d="m2.32 52.3h14.2"/>
    <path d="m37.9 52.3h14.2v-35.6"/>
    <path d="m52.1 52.3v14.2"/>
    <path d="m102 87.8h-14.2"/>
    <path d="m66.3 87.8h-14.2v49.8"/>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g fill-opacity="0">
   <rect x="-68.8" y="16.7" width="56.9" height="35.6" onclick="alert('You have clicked room 1')"/>
   <rect x="-11.9" y="16.7" width="64" height="35.6" onclick="alert('You have clicked room 2')"/>
   <rect x="52.1" y="16.7" width="49.8" height="71.1" onclick="alert('You have clicked room 3')"/>
   <rect x="-68.8" y="52.3" width="71.1" height="56.9" onclick="alert('You have clicked room 4')"/>
   <rect x="2.32" y="52.3" width="49.8" height="85.3" onclick="alert('You have clicked the hallway')"/>
   <rect x="52.1" y="87.8" width="49.8" height="49.8" onclick="alert('You have clicked room 6')"/>
   <rect x="-68.8" y="109" width="71.1" height="28.4" onclick="alert('You have clicked room 5')"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick answer! I dropped it into my code and it worked immediately :-) However, I have 2 Problems. 1) I hate the idea that I have to redraw everything by hand. I certainly would not want to redraw [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topkap%C4%B1_Palace#/media/File:Harem_Topkapi_Palace_plan(2).svg), for example. Which is why I wanted to overlay two images. While you say "GIMP is a raster image editor", it can export SVG with paths, which is why I had hoped to overlay those with original the image. 2) #3  and #4 speak of rectangles. What if a room is not rectangular?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica The shape of the room doesn't matter. You can create a filled path instead of a rectangle.  Redrawing everything by hand is more efficient and the best quality, and it will only take a few minutes with practice. It's not complicated.  Complex work like the example you showed isn't made with Inkscape. That's likely CAD software.  GIMP can export vectors, but it's too basic. You can't add fills or strokes or do anything useful with them like boolean operations.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica - SVGs can contain raster images too. So, if you really don't want to redraw anything, you could technically remove the white background of the jpeg in GIMP, export as transparent PNG. Import it into Inkscape, draw the filled rectangles/shapes, and add the interactivity. However a raster image won't scale well or look as good as a vector image.  Might also be possible to autorace the jpeg in Inkscape, but autorace is not a way to make good quality graphics compared to hand drawn.

Comment: Hmm, drawing is *really* not my thing. I guess that I could pay someone on Fivvr. Thanks for the great feedback

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Sites like Fivvr are viewed as exploitative by the graphic design community. Also, you will get what you pay for.

Comment: I would imagine that you are frustrated by the n00b seeming to be unwilling to listen to what is best. If so, I feel your pain. I am a programmer, and my decades of experience can tell me when someone just isn't listening. If there really is no other way than to trace the entire image by hand, then either I will do so, or I will pay someone to do so. Any idea how much I would pay for a complex floorplan, like the one linked from a previous comment?

Comment: Also, as a coder, I have looked at Fivvr and am amazed to see people expecting me to code FaceBook for $25 :-)

Comment: Yep, Fivvr isn't good.  I'm not frustrated by noobs, but if you ask graphic designers, then you should expect graphic designer answers and opinions.  Anyway, to find out how much it would cost a graphic designer to do it for you, the best way is to ask one for an estimate first. Everyone has different rates, and it often depends where the designer is located.  Complex floorplans aren't created by graphic designers. Technical drawing and CAD is a different field. Try an architect.

Comment: I am about to accept your answer, but then post one of my own, as I need somewhere to explain things, which is too big for a comment & I don't want to pollute the question. Check bag in 2 or 30 minutes, and thanx a 1,000,000 for your help.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica - maybe best to ask a different question if you want to know something else. That's usually the way things work here. You can reference this question in your new question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to ask a new question,. I just want to use a pseudo-answer as a scratchpad, to explain what I am trying to achieve and how I ma resolving it (I have reached "good enough for now").

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica - GDSE and stack exchange sites aren't really set up for doing that kind of thing in answers. I'd recommend you don't do it, because if it's not actually an answer to the question it will likely just be deleted by the mods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129032/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-mawg-says-reinstate-monica).

Comment: It actually was an answer, but it takes 12 pages of MS Word with more than 20 screenshots, so I won't bother posting. No ned for chat. I'm done now, and thank you once again for your great help.